# jquery event handler only running once

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am having problems with jqueries "click" event handler, its working only once, and then it stops, please I need help fixing it.

What I did is, I use an image as a button, for my Web app but, through jquery, but it only runs once.

Here is the code:

```
$( document ).ready(function refresh() {
    $(".menu_button").click(() => {
        $("nav").addClass("open-menu");
    });
});

$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".cancel_menu").click(() => {
        $("nav").removeClass("open-menu").css("transform", "translatex(100%)").css("transition-duration", "2s")
    });
});
```

Please tell me if you need more info, Thanks.

Comment: Can you share a codepen or something?

Comment: Hard to say much without any HTML etc., but perhaps your problem has something to do with the fact, that you never remove the styles applied in $(".cancel_menu").click() ?

Comment: @Khalil Please don't ask for codepen  or jsfiddle when a stack snippet would work just as well. We prefer to keep everything here.

Comment: Thanks, "kpro", but it has nothing to do with its styling, cause with normal javascript it, works, but it doesn't perform its slide animation. I will add some html.

Comment: By the way, how do I edit my question? , I'm kinda new here.

Comment: Well, I couldn't find a way to modify my question so, here are some of the html:    "<img class="cancel_menu" src="cancel.png">
        <ul>
          <li><a class='list1' href="#">settings</a></li>
          <li><a class="list2" href="#">sort</a></li>
          <li><a class="list3" href="#">chat</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <img class='menu_button' src="menu_button.png"> "

Comment: And css: "nav {
  position: fixed;
  border-left: 4px solid;
  border-top: 4px solid;
  border-top-left-radius: 12px;
  border-bottom: 4px solid;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 12px;
  right: 0;
  background: #fdfdfd;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 50%;
  z-index: 999;
  transform: translatex(100%);
}  ".  it was supposed to slide out and slide in, but it only happens once. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I don't think is with the jquery. Your cancel menu moves the menu all the way to the right, but you never bring it back.

I reset the transform to none on the click of the menu button and it works.

Below is the relevant line in the menu_button click event handler

```
$("nav").addClass("open-menu").css("transform", "none");
```

```js
$( document ).ready(function refresh() {
    $(".menu_button").click(() => {
        $("nav").addClass("open-menu").css("transform", "none");
    });
});

$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".cancel_menu").click(() => {
        $("nav").removeClass("open-menu").css("transform", "translatex(100%)").css("transition-duration", "2s")
    });
});
```

```css
.open-menu{
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="menu_button">OPEN</button>
<button class="cancel_menu">CANCEL</button>
<nav>NAV</nav>
```

Comment: @DavidLawal, there really is only one line that is relevant here and I added that to my answer separately so you could see it. That is the only change needed.